Nuxt.js form submits with every data change
I have this form:
<template>
    <div class="flex flex-col mt-[5rem] gap-4 p-4 items-center max-w-4xl mx-auto">      
        <form id="inquiry" class="flex flex-col gap-4 w-full" @submit.prevent="submitHandler">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input class="input" type="text" name="name" v-model="formData.name" @input="saveFormData">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input class="input" type="email" name="email" v-model="formData.email" @input="saveFormData">
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea class="input" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" v-model="formData.message"
                @input="saveFormData"></textarea>
            <h2 v-if="message">{{ message }}</h2>
            <button type="submit" class="btn" :disabled="message === 'Loading...'">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

const message = ref('');
const formData = reactive({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    message: ''
});

const loadFormData = () => {
    const savedData = localStorage.getItem('inquiryFormData');
    if (savedData) {
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(savedData);
        formData.name = parsedData.name || '';
        formData.email = parsedData.email || '';
        formData.message = parsedData.message || '';
    }
};

const saveFormData = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('inquiryFormData', JSON.stringify(formData));
};

const clearFormData = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('inquiryFormData');
};

onMounted(() => {
    loadFormData();
});

const submitHandler = async () => {
    if (message.value === 'Loading...') return; 
    message.value = 'Loading...';

    const { data: res } = await useFetch("***", {
        method: "POST",
        query: {
            websiteId: "***",
            formGroupId: "***"
        },
        body: formData
    });

    const responseMessage = (res.value as any).message;
    message.value = responseMessage === "success"
        ? "Thank you for your inquiry! We will reach out to you shortly."
        : "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";

    formData.name = '';
    formData.email = '';
    formData.message = '';
    clearFormData();
};


</script>

Once I submit, a second submit is sent with the fields blank. If I don't clear the fields, every change to a field triggers another submit. It seems that the handler is watching for field changes. When I log every time the handler is called, it's only called once, but the data is sent multiple times.

useFetch automatically watches params change. That's why when the form fields are cleared, another trigger happens.
The solution is just adding watch: false in the useFetch options.

Documentation
